# I cannot join volley 1.1.1 In Syria, it is prohibited, but I use the proxy. Is there a way to communicate?

Tags: android, android-volley, implementation

I cannot sync Volley dependency to my project

```
buildscript {
 repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}


implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
```

**Show me this error**

```
Could not resolve com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.1.1.
Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/mcxiaoke/volley/library/1.1.1/library-1.1.1.pom'.
Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/mcxiaoke/volley/library/1.1.1/library-1.1.1.pom'.
```

Comment: It's prohibited

Comment: (maven, jitpack, jcenter, ...) are blocked in sanctioned countries. e.g. Syria, Iran, North Korea, etc, use a vpn

Answer (score 0):

I have used volley.jar 2014 And I called him inside  I could not use volley 1.1.1